# Some PHP errors don't appear in the browser

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I'm working in a Laravel 5 application. I have been playing around with the configuration values and creating routes, controllers, models and views. I used to view all PHP errors in the browser, but now, I don't understand why. I just get some errors. In some case, the browser just returns the `500 http error (Internal server error)`.

For example, if I call a url that don't have a correspondent route, I get an error description in the browser. If I have a route pointing to a controller that does not exist, I only receive the `500 http error`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions problem, specifically on the storage folder, i.e. Laravel cannot write to the log file. Just running `chmod -R 755 storage` from the root of the project and the problem was resolve.